# Unnecessary return required with recursion and restart Application

Tags: java, css, recursion, javafx, return

I recreated the game 2048 in Java and it actually works (I didn't expect myself to actually be able to make something "advanced" like this.)

When tiles in the game have moved, a new square/tile/number has to be created, so the code searches for an available spot by randomly picking a number between 0 and 15 ( the tiles have been numbered 0 to 15 (actually it's a multidimensional array with 4 columns and 4 rows)). After picking a random spot it checks if there's already a square/tile/number there, if it is, it recalls this function by returning itself. Because of this, I now also have to return something when the spot wasn't occupied, so I simply returned a number which I don't use afterwards. What do I do wrong?

Something else, to start a new game, I now basically reset all variables in the newGame(); function. Is there a way to restart the application or something like that? Couldn't find anything on the site.

I'd also like to know if I adhered to programming conventions, and general comments on my approach on recreating this for practise. (I understand if this consumes to much of your time).

Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test2048 extends Application{

int score = 0;
Label scoreLabel = new Label("Score: 0");
Label statusLabel = new Label("");
int[][] cell;
Label[][] labels = new Label[4][4];

public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

private void init(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setTitle("2048");

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setVgap(-10);
    grid.setHgap(-10);
    grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #BBADA0; -fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-max-width: 1;  -fx-border-radius: 16; -fx-border-width: 10; -fx-border-color: #F4F4F4; ");
    addLabels(grid);

    newGame();
    Button newGame = new Button("New Game");
    newGame.setOnAction(e -> {
        score = 0;
        statusLabel.setText("");
        newGame();
    });

    VBox layout = new VBox();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(grid, scoreLabel, statusLabel, newGame);

    Scene firstScene = new Scene(layout, 390, 450);
    firstScene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        String arrow = e.getCode().toString();
        switch(arrow){
            case "RIGHT": move(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4); break;
            case "DOWN": move(4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3); break;
            case "LEFT": move(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4); break;
            case "UP": move(4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0); break;
        }
    });
    primaryStage.setScene(firstScene);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    init(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void addLabels(GridPane grid) {
    for (int x=0;x<4;x++){
        for (int y=0;y<4;y++){
            labels[x][y]=new Label();
            grid.add(labels[x][y], x, y);
        }
    }
}

private void newGame(){
    cell = new int[4][4];
    newCell();
    newCell();
    updateScreen();
}

private void move(int ax, int bx, int cx, int dx, int ay, int by, int cy, int dy) {
    boolean hor = false;
    if (ax == 4){
        hor = true;
    }

    Boolean hasMoved = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        int hasChanged;
        if(hor){
            ax = bx = cx = dx = i;
        }else{
            ay = by = cy = dy = i;
        }

        hasChanged = 4;
        if (cell[cx][cy] != 0) {
            if (cell[dx][dy] != 0) {
                if (cell[cx][cy] == cell[dx][dy]) {
                    cell[cx][cy] = 0;
                    cell[dx][dy] *= 2;
                    score += cell[dx][dy];
                    hasChanged = 1;
                    hasMoved = true;
                }
            } else {
                cell[dx][dy] = cell[cx][cy];
                cell[cx][cy] = 0;
                hasMoved = true;
            }
        }

        if (cell[bx][by] != 0) {
            if (cell[cx][cy] != 0) {
                if (cell[bx][by] == cell[cx][cy]) {
                    cell[bx][by] = 0;
                    cell[cx][cy] *= 2;
                    score += cell[cx][cy];
                    hasChanged = 0;
                    hasMoved = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (cell[dx][dy] != 0) {
                    if (cell[bx][by] == cell[dx][dy] && hasChanged != 1) {
                        cell[bx][by] = 0;
                        cell[dx][dy] *= 2;
                        score += cell[dx][dy];
                        hasChanged = 1;
                        hasMoved = true;
                    } else {
                        cell[cx][cy] = cell[bx][by];
                        cell[bx][by] = 0;
                        hasMoved = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    cell[dx][dy] = cell[bx][by];
                    cell[bx][by] = 0;
                    hasMoved = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (cell[ax][ay] != 0) {
            if (cell[bx][by] != 0) {
                if (cell[ax][ay] == cell[bx][by]) {
                    cell[ax][ay] = 0;
                    cell[bx][by] *= 2;
                    score += cell[bx][by];
                    hasMoved = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (cell[cx][cy] != 0) {
                    if (cell[ax][ay] == cell[cx][cy] && hasChanged != 0) {
                        cell[ax][ay] = 0;
                        cell[cx][cy] *= 2;
                        score += cell[cx][cy];
                        hasMoved = true;
                    } else {
                        cell[bx][by] = cell[ax][ay];
                        cell[ax][ay] = 0;
                        hasMoved = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (cell[dx][dy] != 0) {
                        if (cell[ax][ay] == cell[dx][dy] && hasChanged != 1) {
                            cell[ax][ay] = 0;
                            cell[dx][dy] *= 2;
                            score += cell[dx][dy];
                            hasMoved = true;
                        } else {
                            cell[cx][cy] = cell[ax][ay];
                            cell[ax][ay] = 0;
                            hasMoved = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        cell[dx][dy] = cell[ax][ay];
                        cell[ax][ay] = 0;
                        hasMoved = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(hasMoved) newCell();

    checkStatus();
    updateScreen();
}

private void checkStatus(){

    long noSpace = 1;
    boolean won = false;

    for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<4;y++){
            noSpace *= cell[x][y];
            if(cell[x][y] == 2048) won = true;
        }
    }
    boolean alive = false;

    if(noSpace != 0){
        for(int x=0;x<3;x++) {
            for(int y=0;y<4;y++) {
                if (cell[x][y] == cell[x + 1][y]) {
                    alive = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
                if (cell[x][y] == cell[x][y+1]){
                    alive = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        alive = true;
    }

    if (!alive){
        statusLabel.setText("Game Over!");
    } else if(won) {
        statusLabel.setText("Won!");
    }
}

private int newCell(){
    int x = (int) (4 * Math.random());
    int y = (int) (4 * Math.random());
    if(cell[x][y] != 0){
        return newCell();
    } else {
        cell[x][y] = twoOrFour();
        return x; //I don't need this x anywhere, but I need to return newCell()
    }
}

private int twoOrFour(){
    double r = Math.random();
    if(r < 0.125){
        return 4;
    }else{
        return 2;
    }
}

private void updateScreen() {

    for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<4;y++){
            labels[x][y].setText(Integer.toString(cell[x][y]));
            labels[x][y].setStyle(cellStyle(cell[x][y]));
        }
    }

    scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + Integer.toString(score));
}

private String cellStyle(int cell) {
    String style = "-fx-min-width: 100; -fx-background-radius: 20; -fx-font: bolder 30 'ClearSans'; -fx-min-height: 100; -fx-alignment: center; -fx-border-radius: 14; -fx-border-width: 10; -fx-border-color: #BBADA0; -fx-background-color: #";
    switch(cell){
        case 2: style+= "EEE4DA"; break;
        case 4: style+= "ECE0C8"; break;
        case 8: style+= "F2B179"; break;
        case 16: style+= "F59563"; break;
        case 32: style+= "F57C5F"; break;
        case 64: style+= "F65D3B"; break;
        case 128: style+= "EDCE71"; break;
        case 256: style+= "EDCC61"; break;
        case 512: style+= "ECC850"; break;
        case 1024: style+= "EDC53F"; break;
        case 2048: style+= "ECC400"; break;
        case 0: style+= "CDC1B4"; break;
        default: style+= "000000"; break;
    }

    style+= ";-fx-text-fill: #";

    if(cell==2||cell==4){
        style+= "776E65;";
    }else if(cell==0){
        style+= "CDC1B4;";
    }else{
        style+= "F9F6F2;";
    }
    return style;
}
}
```

Comment: If you need to take advantage of recursion but don't intend to do anything with the return value, just have the function return `void` and when you hit the base case, just use the `return` keyword.

Comment: Nice practice program.  One suggestion, look at all the similar code you have in your move method.  See if you can figure out a way to pull that repeated code out into a method, and call the method with different arguments for each x, y pair.

Comment: Thanks Ryan J, I thought you always had to return a recursion thing, don't know where I read that... And Tony, I'll try to do that, i used to have separate methods for going each of the four sides, so this is already a bit better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in @RyanJ's comment, you just define `newCell()` with `void` return type:

```
private void newCell() {
    int x = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
    int y = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
    if (cell[x][y] != 0) {
        newCell();
    } else {
        cell[x][y] = twoOrFour();
    }
}
```

Notice you can just do the same thing with a loop:

```
private void newCell() {
    int x ;
    int y ;
    do {
        x = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
        y = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
    } while (cell[x][y] != 0);
    cell[x][y] = twoOrFour();
}
```

Neither of these is particularly good though, because it could take an arbitrarily long time to find an empty space. In the recursive version, it's even worse, because you could just get unlucky enough for the recursion to run deep enough to cause a `StackOverflowException`. (It's very very unlikely, but if you play long enough (and let's face it, this game is addictive), it will happen sometime.)

Here's a better solution. Create a list of the empty cells (just a list of integers which lie between 0 and 15 inclusive). Then pick one at random:

```
private void newCell() {
    List<Integer> availableCells = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        int x = i / 4 ;
        int y = i % 4 ;
        if (cell[x][y] == 0) {
            availableCells.add(i);
        }
    }
    int nextCell = availableCells.get((int)(Math.random() * availableCells.size()));
    cell[nextCell / 4][nextCell % 4] = twoOrFour();
}
```

Comment: (And, nice job, btw.)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about the do while loop, and I didn't know of the last method.